# Trying to call a .NET function from VBA - using RUN in VBA

Tags: .net, vba, excel

I have a .Net class library and have done all things needed to include it in excel. (expoting as COM visible, for com-interop and regasm'ing the dll as well)
I use excel 2007. In the excel addins, I see my 'TestLib.Functions' as checked. I am able to access the function in my VBA code as :

```
Set lib = New TestLib.Functions
returnVal = lib.Add(5);
```

This works fine.

For other code review reasons, I also saw some functions from another library accessed using the RUN method as :

```
Run("avSomeFunction", paramvalue)
```

Now, in the VBA editor, if I try to access the 'Add' function in the same way,

```
Run("Add", 5)
```

I get an error saying 'Cannot find a macro with name Add'. Is it neccesary that I should 
add tlb as a reference once again in the VB editot-tools-references again, apart from doing Regasm for the .net dll? Can someone please let me know what is the problem here.

p.s : for some very crazy reason, I just had this working once suddenly but again failed to work there after. very weird:(

Comment: please see the answer and the thread mentioned in the below answer for a more close answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Difference between : adding a tlb as reference to invoke function VS using 'Run'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7000758/448314) has the answer to this. Basically, I was missing the reference to the tlb in the VBA project. Apart from registering the dll, the tlb also needs to be added as a reference.

Comment: marking this as answer as this thread has more information related to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Althought your question is not very straight-forward, I think that the links below will assist you in getting the solution to your problem.

First, I found a [forum post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=44229&page=1) explaining the same type of error you explain, "Cannot find Macro".

Second, if that doesn't work try researching using the links provided below:

- [How to properly register your COM Library using RegAsm](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/register-dll.html)
- [Beginners Guide to using .NET in VBA](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/)
- [Create .NET COM Library for VBA](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html)

If this does not solve your problem, please edit your question to include additional information.